# VS code: How to set up the code runner in Visual Studio Code such that the command does not print out when the code is being executed in a terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-code-runner

Is there a way in VS Code to stop printing the command that the code runner executes? It takes up a lot of room and occasionally makes the result hard to read.[image]

Comment: how do you then expect that your program gets compiled

Comment: I just want to hide that